# getting conversation window extension displayed automatically when a conversation window is opened

Tags: lync

I am writing a silverlight application for Lync 2013 to open a conversation window extension.
It works fine if I open a conversation window and go to "more options" and click the menu entry. The conversation window extension is displayed. However is it possible to get the conversation Window extension displayed when opening the conversation window without other click on the "more options" menu?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the CWE from the automation like so:

```
void ConversationManager_ConversationAdded(object sender, Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ConversationManagerEventArgs e)
{            
    var automation = LyncClient.GetAutomation();
    var window = automation.GetConversationWindow(e.Conversation);

    window.BeginOpenExtensibilityWindow(appGuid, EndOpendExtensibilityWindow, state);
}
```